# Use OTP instead of password in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, one-time-password

I have 3 different devise models. Two using `email` & `password` for login and works great. But For the third one I need to use `mobile` & `OTP` based login instead of `email` & `password`. So the devise session controller only receives `mobile` & the `otp` as `params`.

I have changed from `email` to `mobile` by using `authentication_keys`

```
    class Customer < ApplicationRecord
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, authentication_keys: [:mobile]
      def email_required?
        false
      end
    
    end
```

I am using devise-jwt for jwt response & overriding sessions_controller like this

```
    class Api::Customers::V1::Auth::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

      def create
        super { @token = current_token }
      end
  
      private
    
      def current_token
        request.env['warden-jwt_auth.token']
      end
    end
```

But now am getting password blank validation error. How can I disable password validation & change to do an otp verification instead?

PS: I have seen several resources on [two factor auth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QioeIEkbDrg&t=187s) . But they all work with `password` validation.

Comment: Hi, have you found solution for this